# Why more than 4 marriages are not allowed for men

Tags: nikah

Four marriages of men are permissible in islam.Holy Prophet attempted 11 marriages, than why it is not allowed for men to get 11 marriages?

Comment: Your statement is not correct the prophet pbuh was never married to 11 women at once, but only to 9 and the amount of 4 wives which sets a limit for the believers applies to those women one is married at once, else if 4 wives died or were divorced should the husband stay unmarried? So it is incorrect to say that 4 marriages are allowed. But being married to 4 wives simultaneously is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Men are not allowed to be married to more than four women simultaneously, because the Quran has put a limit of four:

> فانكحوا ما طاب لكم من النساء مثنى وثلاث و**رباع** فإن خفتم ألا تعدلوا فواحدة أو ما ملكت أيمانكم ذلك أدنى ألا تعولوا
>
> Then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or **four**. But if you fear that you will not be just, then [marry only] one or those your right hand possesses. That is more suitable that you may not incline [to injustice].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:3](http://quran.com/4/3)</sup>

The Prophet Muhammad ﷺ was married to nine women simultaneously, and this was a specifically allowed to him see [Quran 33:50-52](https://quran.com/33/50-52):

There are quite a few examples of differences of law applicable to the Prophet compared to other Muslims. For example:

- The Prophet and his family can not receive Zakat, whereas any other Muslim may receive it.
- The Prophet's property is not inherited by his heirs, unlike the property of other Muslims.
- Some of the acts of worship that are voluntary for other Muslims are obligatory for the Prophet.
- The Prophet's Wives can not be married by others after his death, unlike the wives of other Muslims.

There is a list of these in [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura33-aya50.html) (arabic)  under السادسة عشرة